# Short coding for toggle value

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to write this shorter? It is just a toggle between true and false value:

```
if (Session.get('editorView')) Session.set('editorView', false);
else Session.set('editorView', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Session.set('editorView',Session.get('editorView') ? false:true );
```

Comment: Good one mate. Should have thought that lol. I was on my phone so typing is an issue. but yeah good one

Answer (score 1):

```
Session.get("editorView") ? Session.set("editorView",false) : Session.set("editorView", true);
```

That's called ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one:

```
Session.set ("editorView", !Session.get("editorView"));
```